# Using RabbitMQ with Log4j2

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, log4j2

My question is  how to configure LOG4J2 to write log in RebbitMQ ? is it possible ?
i tried this config :

```
    <RabbitMQ name="rabbitmq"
              addresses="http://10.0.0.107:15672"
              user="guest"
              password="guest"
              virtualHost="/"
              exchange="log4j2Sample"
              applicationId="log4j2SampleAppId"
              routingKeyPattern="%X{applicationId}.%c.%p"
              contentType="text/plain"
              contentEncoding="UTF-8"
              generateId="false"
              deliveryMode="PERSISTENT"
              charset="UTF-8"
              senderPoolSize="3"
              maxSenderRetries="5">
    </RabbitMQ>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework.amqp.samples.log4j2" level="debug" >
    <AppenderRef ref="rabbitmq" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

but i have no result .